# How to remove some fields of an Object in Spring Boot response control?

Tags: spring-boot

this is one of my REST controller,

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users/Ache")
public class Users {
    @GetMapping
    public User getUser() {
        User user = new User();
        return user;
    }
}
```

As response, Spring boot will translate my Object to JSON,
this is response:

```
{
    "username": "Ache",
    "password": "eee",
    "token": "W0wpuLAUQCwIH1r2ab85gWdJOiy2cp",
    "email": null,
    "birthday": null,
    "createDatetime": "2019-03-15T01:39:11.000+0000",
    "updateDatetime": null,
    "phoneNumber": null
}
```

I want to remove `password` and `token` fields, How can I do?

I know two hard ways:

- create a new hash map

  and add some necessary fields, but it too complex
- set those two fields to null
  but it still leaves two null valued fields, it is too ugly.

Any better solution?

Comment: I have tried code from the below URL and it is working fine: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-dynamically-ignore-fields-while-serial

Answer (score 12):

Spring leverages Jackson library for JSON marshalling by default. The easiest solution that comes to mind is making use of Jackson's @JsonIgnore but that would ignore the property on both serialization and de-serialization. So the right approach would be annotating the field with `@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)`.

For instance, inside a hypothetical User class:

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;

@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String token;
```

An alternative would be using `@JsonIgnore` only on the getter:

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}
```

You can also create another class, for instance `UserResponse` with all the fields except `password` and `token`, and make it your return type. Of course it involves creating an object and populating it, but you leave your `User` class clean without Jackson annotations, and de-couples your model from your representation.

Comment: When adding @JsonIgnore it's going to ignore the password in request as well

Comment: @s1n7ax If you cared to read my whole answer you'd see I made a comment on that, and also an alternative with annotating the getter. Was it you who voted me down then?

Comment: However, thanks for the comment. I edited the code snippet and explanations to avoid confusions and potential further downvotes :)

Comment: very goon nice and thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Keep the getter and setter but add the `WRITE_ONLY` `JsonProperty`. This way password validations will work when you use the entity as the request body.

```java
@NotBlank
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;
```